# Will Laravel also rollback a Model properties when transaction fails?

Tags: php, laravel

If a model could not be saved because transaction failed and we rolled back, so does this will also rollback models properties and $model->exists will true or not because this is saved in model property ?

Comment: No. The application-side of things are not affected by a failing transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If transaction fails, It won't revert Model properties. Transaction is only related to database.

Please check [Laravel Transaction Details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions) for more.

Thanks

Comment: I've done some basic testing, and this seems to be the case. Assuming you're using MySQL, the response from the database will include the primary key which Eloquent then assigns to the model. If you then rollback the transaction the model will still contain the ID, which won't exist in the database. The methodology I'm using to work around this is to catch any expecting, roll the transaction back, set the $exists property to false manually, and nullify the primary key (id) attribute on the model. It kind of sucks.